# Parse Same level Node in SOAP UI and Groovy

Tags: xpath, groovy, xml-parsing, soapui

I have below XML and want to parse to get values

```
<member>
    <name>accumulatorInformation</name>
    <value>
        <array>
            <data>
                <value>
                    <struct>
                        <member>
                            <name>accumulatorEndDate</name>
                            <value>
                                <dateTime.iso8601>20161004T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>accumulatorID</name>
                            <value>
                                <i4>1</i4>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>accumulatorStartDate</name>
                            <value>
                                <dateTime.iso8601>20160904T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>accumulatorValue</name>
                            <value>
                                <i4>0</i4>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                    </struct>
                </value>
                <value>
                    <struct>
                        <member>
                            <name>accumulatorEndDate</name>
                            <value>
                                <dateTime.iso8601>20161017T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>accumulatorID</name>
                            <value>
                                <i4>2</i4>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>accumulatorStartDate</name>
                            <value>
                                <dateTime.iso8601>20160917T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>accumulatorValue</name>
                            <value>
                                <i4>0</i4>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                    </struct>
                </value>
            </data>
        </array>
    </value>
</member>
```

I tried to parse and only want accumulatorID and accumulatorValue.

Following is my code in SOAPUI as groovy step

```
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Get#Response")
for( struct in responseHolder.getNodeValues( "//member[name='accumulatorInformation']/value/array/data/value/struct/*" ))
log.info "struct : [$struct]"
log.info "accumulatorID : " + struct.getNodeValues( "//member[name='accumulatorID']/value/descendant::*" )
```

It shows output like below and second line showing error

```
Mon Sep 26 16:54:01 GST 2016:INFO:struct : [  ]
Mon Sep 26 16:54:01 GST 2016:INFO:struct : [  ]
Mon Sep 26 16:54:01 GST 2016:INFO:struct : [  ]
```

Comment: Both elements are repeating and not simple values. What are the expected values for each element?

Comment: accumulatorID = 1 
accumulatorValue = 0
accumulatorID = 2
accumulatorValue = 0

Comment: Thank you for the details. Can you provide the parsable xml while it has all the details that are need as per original xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml is not well formatted but this

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

content =   """    <value>
         <struct>
           <member>
              <name>accumulatorEndDate</name>
              <value><dateTime.iso8601>20161004T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601></value>
           </member>
           <member>
             <name>accumulatorID</name>
             <value><i4>1</i4></value>
           </member>
           <member>
             <name>accumulatorStartDate</name>
                 <value><dateTime.iso8601>20160904T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601></value>
           </member>
           <member>
             <name>accumulatorValue</name>
             <value><i4>0</i4></value>
           </member>
      </struct>
      </value>

      """
      def p =  new XmlSlurper().parseText(content)



      // def v= p.value.struct.member[0].name.text()
       assert "accumulatorEndDate"==p.struct.member[0].name.text().toString()

        println (p.struct.member[1].value.i4.text())
        println (p.struct.member[3].value.i4.text())
```

will print the required values

```
1
0
```

you can also do

```
  p.struct.member.each{
    println "${it.name.text()} "
    println "${it.value.text()} "


   }
```

to print these

```
accumulatorEndDate 
20161004T12:00:00+0000 
accumulatorID 
1 
accumulatorStartDate 
20160904T12:00:00+0000 
accumulatorValue 
0
```

Answer (score 3):

Following groovy script extracts Ids in a list and values in a separate list.

```
//Pass your xml string 
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

//closure to search for the given element in the xml
def searchData = { data, element -> data.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'name' && it == element }*.parent().value.i4 }

//Using the above closure to search `accumulatorID` and `accumulatorValue` respectively
def accumulatorIds = searchData(parsedXml, 'accumulatorID')
def accumulatorValues = searchData(parsedXml, 'accumulatorValue')
println accumulatorIds
println accumulatorValues
```

The script can be quickly tried using [this](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5097453078446080) link.
Hope this helps.